# How to get a File Explorer/Navigator to work in Adobe AIR applications?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, air

I realize this is probably a simple question but my google-fu is failing me. I would like to get a windows explorer like file browser to popup when I click a button to select images to upload to my AIR application. However I cannot find a component that handles File exploring. Does anyone know what to use? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/FileSystemTree.html You can also find samples if you will search for "flex FileSystemTree"